# PXE boot with VMware like Xen

Tags: xen, pxe, citrix

Citrix XenServer has a really nice feature where, when creating a new virtual machine, you can manually set PXE options, and you don't need to have a dedicated machine for holding PXE boot loaders and such. You don't even have to configure your DHCP servers at all. Basically, the DHCP / PXE / TFTP functions are handled by XenServer directly.

My question is, can this be done in VMware, or do you have to create a virtual machine specifically for handling PXE, and then configure your DHCP?

For the record, I'm NOT talking about this product: http://labs.vmware.com/flings/pxe-manager. That's for PXE booting ESXi hosts, not individual virtual machines.

See the image below for what I'm talking about:

[image: XenServer boot options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware workstation doesn't have that feature.

You can boot from a CD/DVD, ISO file, or from the net.  When you boot from the net you will need a PXE server.

--if you guys edit my answer please do not change the idea of the answer--

net != internet